# Is there a way for an app[iphone] to determine programmatically if another specific app is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

Can I code an app to check if another app is runnin?

For example This would be the code for app1

app1.m
Check
{
if(app2.running)
{
do something...
}

Comment: Which platform? for Windows, it should be YES.

Comment: @YigangWu: please check his tags, he is asking for iOS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the category defined in the link below to get a list of running processes, and look for the target process name.

http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone you can't do this. Each app is "sandboxed" which basically separates it entirely from every other app on the system.

Sorry.